# Can a US visa invitation letter be in an email or must it be an original?

Tags: visas, usa, invitation-letters

I have been accepted to attend a conference in the US, and they will be covering all the costs (transportation, lodging...), but I only received the invitation by email.

Do US visa offices accept a faxed or emailed invitation letter or I should request an original one?

Answer (score 1):

Note that an invitation letter is not technically required, but it can  almost certainly help.  [From the US Embassy website](https://do.usembassy.gov/need-invitation-u-s-citizen-someone-u-s-order-qualify-tourist-visa/):

> An invitation is not required and cannot guarantee visa issuance. In
>   fact, there are no required documents for tourist/business visa
>   applications.

It's more about documenting your reasons for visit, and evidence that you'll leave in a timely manner, etc.

> For tourist/business visas, the most commonly applied for visa class,
>   applicants must be able to demonstrate to the satisfaction of the
>   consular officer that their travel plans fall within the parameters of
>   the requested visa class – limited travel for pleasure or business
>   (but not employment) of short durations.  Applicants must also be able
>   to demonstrate that they will depart the United States in a timely
>   manner to return to their residence abroad.

As a result, email or letter won't matter, it's not 'official' it's just additional useful documentation. It should contain useful information that can be checked. From [Sampleinvitationletter.info](http://www.sampleinvitationletter.info/invitation-letter-for-us-visa-b2-tourist.php):

the following should be in the letter of invitation.

> Your letter should include the following information about the person
>   being invited:
>
> ```
> Complete name.
> Date of birth.
> The person’s address and telephone number.
> Your relationship to the person being invited.
> The purpose of the trip.
> How long the person you are inviting intends to stay in the United States of America.
> Details on accommodation and living expenses.
> The date the person you are inviting intends to leave the USA.
> ```
>
> Your letter should also include the following information about the
>   person writing the letter:
>
> ```
> Complete name.
> Date of birth.
> Address and telephone number in the United States.
> Occupation.
> Your status in the United States
> A photocopy of a document proving your status in the United States.
> ```